# Как правильно добавлять файл стилей на WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как правильно добавлять файлы CSS и JavaScript на WordPress с помощью `bloginfo` или функций `wp_enqueue_script ()`, `wp_enqueue_style ()`?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример - код надо добавить в functions.php [дочерней темы](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

```
function my_scripts() {
    // Theme stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    // Theme script
    wp_register_script('my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Подробнее [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: про кастмный js хорошо написал, а с css не очень  ;) Стоит поправить код.

Comment: @SeVlad http://cs5.pikabu.ru/post_img/big/2015/12/04/5/1449210847155432089.jpg  )))

Comment: эээх :)) https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: Зачем вообще  ТАК подключать style.css ТЕМЫ, если он и так подключается

Comment: @SeVlad  а если серьезно, то обычно style.css один, ни от чего не зависит. Код рабочий.

Comment: @SeVlad хрена с два он сам подключается, если тема самописная с нуля. Только что проверил на одном из своих сайтов.

Comment: Код.. бесполезный (в части css). Не подключиться  style.css ТЕМЫ просто не может - тему ВП тупо увидит. Это же единственный обязательный файл темы.

Comment: @SeVlad Я тебе говорю - только что проверил. Могу сайт показать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61787/discussion-between-sevlad-and-kagg-design).

Answer (score -1):

В папке с темой создаешь отдельный файл (custom_function.php)
В него через кастомные функции подключаешь свои файлы js и css. И не забываешь про add_action.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
// add_action('wp_print_styles', 'theme_name_scripts'); // можно использовать этот хук он более поздний
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

А потом свой файл custom_function добавляешь в файл function.php твоей темы.

Comment: Это какие-то новые новости в WordPress. Нет такого файла и непонятно, с чего бы он стал обрабатываться ядром.

Comment: В ядре WordPress всего 18 вхождений текста functions.php, среди них нет подключения файла с составным именем *functions.php.

Вхождения function.php (без s) вообще нет.

Comment: Чем использовать такой ммм.. гемморой, лучше поставить https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/ А вообще лучше как KAGG Design написал - через дочку.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.