# не подключается файл mystyle.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap

Пишу тему на wordpress. Подключил сторонние библиотеки все нормально, а мой файл со стилями не срабатывает....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/mystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Данное подключение тоже не срабатывает
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/style/mystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/style.css">
    -->
    <!-- И это тоже подключение тоже не срабатывает
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/mystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    -->
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="red">RED</h1>
```

mystyle.css:

```
.red {
    color: red;
    }
```

footer.php:

```
         <!--  FOOTER   -->
    <h1>FOOTER</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>        
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Добавление wp_head() и wp_footer() тоже не решило проблему....

создан дефолтный проект wordpress, создал в темах папку wp_my_themes (wordpressproject.com/www/wp-content/themes).

содержимое папки wp_my_themes:

```
 style          (в этой папке лежит файл mystyle.css)
 404.php        (файл пуст)
 footer.php     (содержимое написано выше)
 functions.php  (файл пуст)
 header.php     (содержимое написано выше)
 index.php      (содержимое написано выше)
 page.php       (файл пуст)
 screenshot.png (картинка темы)     
 style.css      (файл пуст, в комментах данные для описания темы)
```

Comment: если вы уверенны что в папке style имеется файл mystyle.css, то при подключении укажите полный путь до файла (base url) возможно поможет

Comment: @Arsen,  Arsen я начал с нуля писать и конечно же я занес в него свойства, которые использую в коде. Сейчас поправлю код для наглядности

Comment: а какой color указан в  style.css  ?

Comment: Попробуйте `href="./style/style.css"`

Comment: @Максим Ленский, в файле style.css НЕ обязательно прописывать стили

Comment: откройте консоль в браузере если не подключен значит путь к файлу не правильный и там будет ошибка `404` для этого файла, посмотрите как сформирован там обсолютная ссылка к файлу, и поймете что не так.

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, да, пишет 404 в консоли когда прописывается полный путь, а если не полный путь, то в консоли все впорядке, а в источниках 404 пишет....

Comment: не надо полный путь писать, тогда это не правильное решение, (но и то если путь правильно будет но не будет `404 not found`) а отрицательный путь вы не правильно пишете, и здесь не кто не может дать конкретно ответ, поскольку иерархию вашего сайта не знает не кто.  просто посмотрите как дают пути к файлам при подключении, (http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki)

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan,  создан дефолтный проект wordpress,  создал в темах папку wp_my_themes (wordpressproject.com/www/wp-content/themes). содержимое в папке сейчас допишу в вопросе

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/mystyle.css">` подобное категорически не правильно. Относительная же ссылка относительно запрашиваемой страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте вот так, если файл стиля находится в папке темы который вы создали

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/css/fonts.css"/>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ  мне помог наконец-то решить эту проблему!

Answer (score 2):

> Пишу тему на wordpress. Подключил сторонние библиотеки все нормально,
>   а мой файл со стилями не срабатывает....

В тему должны быть включены функции [wp_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) и [wp_footer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/). Это избавит от многих проблем, а не только с подключением стилей.

Но если вдруг есть устойчивое желание не использовать вышеупомянутые функции, то нужно подключать вручную с пом [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).
//**Добавка**. все другие стили (не style.css) *обязательно* должны быть подключены через эту функцию, вне зависимости от наличия `wp_head()` и `wp_footer()`//

См [Как правильно подключить файл стилей в своей теме WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688720/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-wordpress/) с ответами и комментами.

Comment: Добавление wp_head() и wp_footer() не решило проблему....С Вашей ссылкой "Как правильно подключить файл стилей в своей теме WordPress?" я тоже ознакомился внимательно, очень хороший ответ, но....к сожалению...это не решило моей проблемы с подключением файла со стилями....

Comment: Если речь о style.css, то не может не решить. Другие подключаются указанной функцией. Надеюсь, то. что написано в вопросе (хедер) всё убрано? Там неправильно написано. Даже путь к файлам стилей неверный.

Comment: Вот [ещё вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688529/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress) из которого родился предыдущий. См комменты а в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61787/discussion-between-sevlad-and-kagg-design) я давл пример минимальной темы. Всё подключается если делать правильно.

Comment: я же так и подключил wp_head() и wp_footer()

Comment: Я обновил ответ. Другие стили (и скрипты) подключаются через функции  wp_enqueue_style.(wp_enqueue_script соответственно)

Answer (score 1):

В консоле пишет что файл не найден?попробуй

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/mystyle.css">

Comment: пишет 404 в консоли когда прописывается полный путь, а если не полный путь, то в консоли все впорядке, а в источниках 404 пишет.... "../" - тоже пробовал

Comment: Попробуй абсолютный путь <link rel="stylesheet" href="/../style/mystyle.css">

Answer (score 0):

Подключение для данного конкретного случая выглядит так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style/mystyle.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/style.css"/>
```